# How to add Assembly reference?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I added `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` to my code but compiler reports error CS0234:

> The type or namespace name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What is this "assembly reference" and how to add one?

Error also shown in the picture
  http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/6517/errorcup.jpg

Comment: In the future, please give both your code and the compiler error directly in the question as text, instead of just posting an image.

Comment: Maybe the OP meant missing?

Comment: Why exactly are you using the VB reference in a C# app? C# can create temp files and do FileIO without VB...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got a `using` directive for the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, but the fact that you're fully-qualifying the name [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.aspx) makes that irrelevant.

I suspect you just haven't added a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` assembly. (Assemblies and namespaces are very different things.)

Personally I would attempt to avoid VB-specific assemblies in the first place, to be honest.