# The type or namespace name 'SQLConnection' could not be found

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Something seems wrong with the c# database for Accounts:

Right at the database I get the error message of:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Connection' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I possibly doing wrong with it? I would like to connect to the database in the Accounts

[image: Table]

Code 1:

```
 public void setCustAccounts(String custId) {

        SQLConnection connect = acctsConnect();
        Command statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String sql = "SELECT acctNo FROM Accounts Where Cid = '" + custId + "';";

        try{
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeQuery(sql);


            while (result.next()){
                result.getRow();
                Account acct = new Account(result.getString("acctNo"));
                custAccounts.add(acct);                
            }
        }

        finally {
            connect.close();
        }
    }
```

**code:-**

```
    public SQLConnection acctsConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }

        SQLConnection connect = null;

        try{
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }

        return connect;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The datatype is a `SqlConnection` - and lower- and upper-case letters **are** significant in C# !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are missing the [using Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) statement in your code.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: At first, you should install _System.Data.SqlClient_ package!

Answer (score 118):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Along with the above line we need to also check if the actual system assembly reference is there or not. In my case I had the directive but [assembly reference was missing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025912/how-to-add-assembly-reference#14025924)

To add assembly we can do the following.

**Browse dll file for SqlClient in and add it.**

--or--- simpler way is to install nuget package.

**Right Click on Project > Manage Nuget Packages > Search & install 'System.Data.SqlClient'**

Make sure it is compatible with the type of project (Core/Standard);

Comment: If I have the targeted framework 4.6.1 and the System.Data.SqlClient v4.6.1, which core/standard is needed to get System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.6 to run? I could not get `GetColumnSchema()` to run, see [Usage of SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema() not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78110309/11154841) and [How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?](https://serverfault.com/a/1155574/607547).

Answer (score 12):

1. Right Click on your project file in the solution panel, and then
   Click on the Manage NuGet Packages option.
2. In the NuGet Package Manager window, Select the Browser Tab. Search for
   System.Data.SqlClient and Press enter
3. Select the first option, System.Data.SqlClient by Microsoft Click on the install button

Wait for the installation to complete. Done.

Source YouTube Video: [SqlConnection could not be found in the namespace | Fixed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQPFaUYxxF4)

Answer (score 7):

As [Community Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11361780/community-ans) says, you should install the NuGet package in your project first. If you don't, Visual Studio's Intellisense will still work when you add the using but you won't be able to use it's types in your code.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The package reference can be added via the [.NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli):

> dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 2):

So for me, VS2022, I had the latest Nuget package and using statement in my project. I deleted the using statement, then went back to the SqlConnection statement in my code, moused over the SqlConnection object, clicked on Show Potential Fixes, clicked on using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient; and it fixed it.

HTH...

Answer (score 2):

Install and use the new System.Data.SqlClient package in NuGet in your project or solution.
Follow these steps to install the package.

1. Right Click on your solution from the solution panel in VS.
2. From the context menu, select the Manage NuGet Packages for solutions...

[image]

3. In the NuGet Package Manager window, select the Browse Tab.
4. In the search box type in **System.Data.SqlClient** and press enter.
5. Look for the package **System.Data.SqlClient** by **Microsoft** and select it.
6. A small panel will open at the right side of the window with the list of projects in your solution. Select only the projects you want the SqlClient package to be installed. Then press the install button. NuGet will install the selected package "System.Data.SqlClient" and all its dependencies.
7. Now go back to your solution or project and rebuild. You will not get the error again.

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukd5z.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution shown above.

Instead of using SQLiteConnection(YourPath), use :

```
     var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DataBasePath);
     db.CreateTable<YourTable>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to Install and use the new System.Data.SqlClient package in NuGet to your project or solution. Follow these steps to install the package.

Right Click on your solution from the solution panel in VS.
From the context menu, select the Manage NuGet Packages for solutions...
In the NuGet Package Manager window, select the Browse Tab.
In the search box type in System.Data.SqlClient and press enter.
Look for the package System.Data.SqlClient by Microsoft and select it.
A small panel will open at the right side of the window with the list of projects in your solution. Select only the projects you want the SqlClient package to be installed.
Then press the install button. Wait for the installation to complete. NuGet will install the selected package and all it’s dependencies.
Now go back to your solution or project and rebuild. You will not get the error again.

Answer (score 0):

You can must remove before all SqlConnection, Sql... code blocks.
After package install and write code.
VS to suggest using System.Data.SqlClient...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error wvwn though I included the namespace but missing thing was the NuGet package of System.Data.SqlClient after installing that it worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dotnet core 3.x or dotnet 5, 6, 7, 8, .....

Then search for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in nuget and then use `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;`, it's solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project > Manage Nuget Packages > Search & install 'System.Data.SqlClient' this one working fine for me