# Could not install package '--'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I created this package, I need it in a project but couldn't install it, this error appears:

> Could not install package 'Mshwf.NiceLinq 1.0.9'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package  does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author

I don't  know why this happen, in another project (Console) I changed the framework to 4.6 and other versions and it wasn't a problem, but this only happen in this project (MVC and Web API):

this is the nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Mshwf.NiceLinq</id>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
    <title>Nice LINQ</title>
    <authors>MShawaf</authors>
    <owners>Mshawaf</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/mshwf/NiceLinq</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mshwf/NiceLinq/master/logo.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>See it as: WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 22, 30, 101)</description>
    <releaseNotes>Minor changes.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>LINQ IEnumerable Where Contains Search Filter</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 41):

Go to the folder:

```
C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages\[package name]\1.0.0.4\lib
```

Rename the folder with the .net version of your project.

Suppose I am using .net framework 4.6.1 my folder name should be `net461`

Comment: What's the downside of this method?

Comment: This solution is the only working one so far for me in order to workaround Microsoft.ServiceHub.Analyzers package, unable to be installed on a project or with any package using this package as a dependency ! Just added the corresponding target version (for me lib\net472) and then copied the root "untargeted" folder in this new folder, and everything worked like a charm, even for packages that needed this as a dependency, like Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0 . Thanks for the trick !

Comment: That seems to be the winning solution for me , thank you.

Comment: It works but renaming these folders can lead to issues with package resolution and compatibility. Therefore, you'd rather rename it back to original right after the installation.

Answer (score 36):

Your package targets NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2. That means the assembly folder is lib\net452. You are trying to install the package to a higher framework (greater than 4.5) project. Create a project with framework 4.5.2 or rename the package's lib folder from net452 to the version which you want to target like net45 or net46.

You can target multiple framework too from a single package.

Edit your csproj file like this:

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>`

Refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks

For a complete, up-to-date list of target framework names, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks

Comment: The Mshwf.NiceLinq 1.0.9 package targets  .NET 4.5.2 which is why it cannot be installed into .NET 4.5 project. So they would need to create a .NET 4.5.2 project. However your answer is nearly correct. I modified your answer to be correct - hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 6):

You can install earlier version like : Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 7.0.1

Answer (score 3):

The .NET Target Framework version is most likely too old. I have VS 2017 and my default Target Framework for a new .NET Framework project was 4.0. I initially tried to install the RestSharp package but it failed with an almost identical message as in this post 'Could not install package ...' However, when I went to Project | Properties | and Application I was able to change the Target Framework to .NET Framework 4.6.1 and then it installed fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to install the package into a WPF App (.Net Framework) while my co-workers prepared the package for .Net Core Project.

Try creating a .Net Core Project(or the type of the targeted project type) and install the packages same way:

> Solution Explorer>Right click to Solution>Manage Nuget Packages for solution>Search for the needed package>Install

Checking this before other solutions may save time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to insert a package of our own making that we put into our own Nuget feed, so I had access to the project. 
This is what I did to clear the issue up. In the project solution window, click on the packages.config. In the properties window, change build action to "Content." After pushing it out to our feed again I was able to install it into the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue which i fixed by removing the packages.config(you can edit the file if you don't want to remove) file and then made sure both the package i was using was built using the same .net version as the Project i was using it in(for me the package was built using 4.6 while my console project was targeting earlier version of .net).

Answer (score 0):

Update the Application .NET target framework could solve the problem. In my case, I'm installing EmguCv 4.2 package. I get this same error when trying to build with 4.5.1 .NET target framework. After updated the .NET target framework to 4.6.2, I can install the EmguCv 4.2 Nuget package successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing .net SDK [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-3.1.302-windows-x64-installer) and then right-click on your solution/project and "restore nuget packages"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a package I had created and hosted on our own private nuget server, but even after trying others suggestions here such as making sure that the package supported the correct .net framework version, it still wouldn't work.

I got someone else to try and they managed to add it with no problem.
Today, messing around in VS's options, I found a fix for this:
Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

[How to clear nuget cache in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRloO.png)

Hopefully this helps someone who was as confused as I was :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to install Itext7 package my project .NET framework was 4.5
I changed my project .NET framework to .NET 4.6.1 by using the following  steps then I installed the package successfully :

1- right click the project and click properties
2- Under application tab change the Target framework to the required framework for your package

Answer (score 0):

I could not install OpenTK package in .NETFramwork app but i had success with .NET Core project

Answer (score 0):

- Check the supported version from `C:\Users \\ [username] \\.nuget\packages\\[package name]\1.0.0.4\lib`.
- Go to Project > Right click and select Properties > Application > Target Framework.
- Change the Target Framework to the supported version.

In my case supported version is net462 for the library.

##### Example

*Here are greenshots of this from another example and from another user:*

[image]

I choose Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v5.2.0 instead of System.Data.SqlClient v4.8.6 for the project since the former is said to replace the latter, see the text:

> This has replaced System.Data.SqlClient.

[image]

I then try to set this new v5.2.0 for the .Net framwork of the project properties, but it is not in the list to choose from for the project even though I can install it:

[image]

[image]

They do not have 5.2 for download, the highest .NET framework that I can choose is v4.8.1:

[image]

I see that I have to change my code as well from System to Microsoft:

[image]

And I still get:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime 5.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I then find that I can upgrade my .NET framework only to v4.8 while v4.8.1 is blocked. Since the v4.8 installation fails (perhaps since I do not have admin rights?), I step back to the older `System.Data.SqlClient v4.6.1`. My framework is now (as it is shown by the error) also v4.6.1. Thus, I install that for the project:

[image]

[image]

After this, you cannot click on "Install" anymore, this has worked:

[image]

Now I run into another error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ...

But that is a new question at [The type or namespace name 'SQLConnection' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733221/the-type-or-namespace-name-sqlconnection-could-not-be-found).