# C# to SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have imported `System.Data.SqlClient`, and I am getting the error:

> type and namespace sqlconnection could not be found.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLapplication 
{
    class DBSQLServerUtils
    {
        public static SqlConnection GetDBConnection(string datasource, string database, string username, string password)
        {
           // datasource = SQLSERVER2016:49773;Intital Catelog = OpalData;persist Sercurity INFO = true; username ID = username;password=12345
           string connString = @"Data Source=" +datasource+";Initial Catalog="+database+";Persist Security Info=True; UserID="+username+";Password="+password;

           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

           return conn;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'SQLConnection' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733221/the-type-or-namespace-name-sqlconnection-could-not-be-found)

Comment: It is strange since your code have no errors. what is the version of Assembly System.Data.