# Usage of SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema() not possible

Tags: c#, database, sqldatareader

i'm trying to use the GetColumnSchema method of the SqlDataReader class. But VS tells me that SqlDataReader does not contain a definition for GetColumnSchema. Do i miss a namespace or assembly reference?

My project is using .NET Framework 4.6.1

```
using System;
using DocuWare.LoggingNew;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

private void WriteSQLQueryOutputToTextFile(string DBUser, string DBUserPassword, string sqlQuery, string databaseName, string nameOfOutputFile)
{
  StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(dWTestResult + "\\DatabaseUpgradeCheck\\" + nameOfOutputFile);           

  using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + GetEnvironmentVariable.MachineName + "; Initial Catalog=" + databaseName + "; User ID=" + DBUser + "; Password=" + DBUserPassword + ";"))
    {
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlCon);
      sqlCon.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {   
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var columnSchema = reader.GetColumnSchema();
            string header = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                header += $", {columnSchema[i].ColumnName}";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Debug(ex, "Writing Database Output to the " + nameOfOutputFile + " file failed");
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
        outputFile.Close();
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1 as Target framework

Comment: `GetColumnSchema` is an extension in `System.Data.Common`. Are you `using System.Data.Common;`?

Comment: Seems like i'm using .net core version 2.1.202

Comment: @haldo Does not fix the problem

Comment: When i use dotnet --version in a command line window it is version 2.1.202. When i open "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" it is version 4.7.03190. 
Aren't the .Net Framework version and .Net Core version two different things?

Comment: dotnet --version just shows which versions of .net core you have installed. You need to look in project properties to get the version the project is using. Please update question with the actual version your project is using.

Comment: I did. I also updated my .Net Core version to 3.0.100

Comment: Have you tried adding `using System.Data.Common;` because `GetColumnSchema` is an extension within that assembly (in .net framework) and your posted code is missing that `using`

Comment: Maybe you need to upgrade to 4.7.1

Comment: I tried @haldo. But it does not work, VS says "Using directive is unnecessary. Seems like it is not part of same namespace any longer?

Comment: @haldo damn you are right. Using .Net version 4.7.1 fixed it. Now, the namespace contains the extension. Thx.

Comment: Now, i get a "Specified method is not supported" System.NotSupportedException. Classic one :D

Answer (score 2):

`SqlDataReader` has a property `GetName()` which takes an index and returns the column name.

[GetName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname?view=netframework-4.7.2) is supported in most .Net framework (from v1.1) and .Net core (from v1.0) versions.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string header = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        header += $", {reader.GetName(i)}";
    }
}
```

Or you can do it using method chaining and Linq:

```
// returns List<string>
var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                        .Select(reader.GetName)
                        .ToList();

// columns joined on ", "
var header = string.Join(", ", columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getcolumnschema?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

Package:
System.Data.SqlClient `v4.8.6`

You write that you have .NET Framework `4.6.1`. I have the same framework and there is no `4.8.6` framework to be targeted at the time of writing. I follow the [Framework targeting overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2022):

[image]

But if I click to install other frameworks, I do not find a `4.8.6` framework so that this high version seems to be needed only for the System.Data.SqlClient. Changing my targeted framework to `4.8` did not make the program run. I did not try `4.8.1` which you could download at the time of writing:

[image]

I doubt that it will change something.

Still, you may try the same, keep or switch the targeted framework, and then update the System.Data.SqlClient to `4.8.6.`:

[image]

Uninstall and install again leads to:

[image]

Then you might get `GetColumnSchema()` from the `Namespace: System.Data.SqlClient`, but for me, it did not work. If the package version `4.8.6` is higher than the highest framework version, I do not know which framework version is needed to make it run. Any remarks are welcome. I am just a beginner at C# and the settings for .NET in Visual Studio.